# Unzip zipped lists in LINQ

Tags: c#, sorting

In a badly spec'd interface we have

```
int[] userIdList; // ids of all users to display
string[] userNameList; // names of all users to display
```

with the restriction that userIdList[i] always contains the ID of the user with the name userNameList[i].

The new requirement is to sort the users by name: I shall take these two lists, sort by name, and return two lists where aforementioned restriction still holds.

Of course I could implement a sort function on my own, but I thought a single-line linq statement could do this even better? I got up to

```
userNameList.Zip(userIdList, (name, id) => new {name, id}).OrderBy(a=>a.name).
```

but now I don't know how to get the lists unzipped again...

Comment: If at all possible, instead of keeping them unzipped, I'd look into just keeping them combined in a single object as long as possible, to ensure that any future manipulations are easier to work with. Once you get your Ids and Names from the interface, merge them to a User object, and use that as much as possible instead. you can still use the syntax suggested by Tim Schmelter if you need one of them separately.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Sorting will occur in the middleware, where these arrays were only passed through on their way from backend to frontend. I guess that in the frontend, they will be zipped again for display *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the input:

```
 int[] userIdList = new []{ 1,5,3,6 }; // ids of all users to display
 string[] userNameList = new []{ "Farix", "Doubles", "Rogue", "Splinter" }; // names of all users to display
```

You could just do:

```
 Array.Sort(userNameList, userIdList);
```

And then you would get exactly the same result as in your LINQ code, but with a simpler expression which doesn't allocate new arrays like in the LINQ code, but just reorders the items in the existing arrays, which is much more efficient.

Comment: This is why I gave the big picture, and did not only point at where I am stuck. :)

Comment: Good approach :) If you just posted the LINQ code without the explanation it would be harder to understand your intent.

Answer (score 7):

```
int[] userIdList = zipped.Select(x => x.id).ToArray();
string[] userNameList = zipped.Select(x => x.name).ToArray();
```

Comment: For your solution to work, the `zipped` collection should be a list, since it is performing the multiple enumerations. There is no way you can unzip an enumerable. Because after unzipping, you would typically expected two  independent enumerable collections which cannot originate from a single enumerable collection. Because you can only enumerate once

Answer (score 1):

You can unzip if the collection is list type. You can write your own unzip extension method to achieve this:

```
 public static class ListExtensions
    {
        public static void Unzip<T, T1, T2>(this IList<T> source, Func<T, T1> firstSelector, Func<T, T2> secondSelector,
            out IEnumerable<T1> first, out IEnumerable<T2> second)
        {
            first = source.Select(firstSelector);
            second = source.Select(secondSelector);
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
enumerableEntitiesToUnzip.ToList().Unzip(e=>e.Prop1,e=>e.Prop2, out var first, out var second)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted something like Scala `unzip()` so I used [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58035949/1507124) of @zafar

```cs
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static (IEnumerable<T1>, IEnumerable<T2>) Unzip<T1, T2>(
        this IEnumerable<(T1, T2)> source
    ) => source.Unzip(tp => tp.Item1, tp => tp.Item2);

    public static (IEnumerable<T1>, IEnumerable<T2>) Unzip<T1, T2>(
        this IEnumerable<(T1, T2)> source,
        Func<(T1, T2), T1> f1,
        Func<(T1, T2), T2> f2
    ) => (source.Select(f1), source.Select(f2));
}
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it is the most functional style of all the ones given; however in my implementation, I folded the list using two collector lists and returned them directly from the function, since `out` variables aren't recommended nowadays. The folding approach also eliminates iterating the collection twice which is happening in the second function.

Comment: @StanleyG. thanks! Long time since I wrote this and can probably be improved, feel free to suggest an edit if the same can be achieved with less iteration 